# Postgres: select all records in 95th percentile

Tags: postgresql, column-alias

I'm trying to query all rows which are in the 95th percentile. Here's what I tried.

```sql
select
  id,
  percentile_cont(0.95) within group (order by usage asc) as percentile_95
from ResourceUsage
where usage > percentile_95
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query fails with `ERROR: column "percentile_95" does not exist` which is caused by the fact that you can't reference in the `WHERE` clause column alias from the `SELECT`.

If you remove the `WHERE` clause you get a different error

```
select
  id,
  percentile_cont(0.95) within group (order by usage asc) as percentile_95
from ResourceUsage

ERROR: column "resourceusage.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Which points you how to calculate the `percentile_cont` for the whole table (i.e. *without* using `GROUP BY`):

```
select
  percentile_cont(0.95) within group (order by usage asc) as percentile_95
from ResourceUsage;

percentile_95             
------------------------- 
95.05
```

Now you are close to the result, get the above result in a subquery and use it in the `WHERE` clause.

```
select
  id,
  usage
from ResourceUsage
where usage > 
 (select
  percentile_cont(0.95) within group (order by usage asc) as percentile_95
 from ResourceUsage);
```